# resize height of div with overflow

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll, overflow

Please help me with CSS to obtain one special visual effect. I have a container div which contains 3 divs inside. 
**First DIV** is hidden;
**Second DIV** is a button which Slide Up and Down the First DIV;
**Third DIV** is a div with Overflow properties which scroll the information inside.

I do not know how to change/adjust the height of DIV-3 when DIV-1 is scrolling down - to keep DIV-3 inside of Div CONTAINER. I hope someone else faced such problem before and can recommend something useful.

Please have a look in my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2xrg6/2/) in order to see the real example. Thank you for your time!

---

EXAMPLE

---

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="updiv">Header info</div>
<div class="middle" onclick="uparrow()">button UP and DOWN</div>
    <div class="bottomdiv">
        <div class="block">111</div>
        <div class="block">222</div>
       <div class="block">333</div>  
      <div class="block">444</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

---

```
.container{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position: relative; 


}
.updiv{
 display:none;
 width:392px;
 height:100px;
  margin:3px;
 border:1px solid blue;
 background:yellow;   
}
.middle{
margin:3px;
 width:392px;
 height:30px;
 background:green;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;   
}
.block{
 width:100%;
 height:100px;   
 background:pink;
 margin-bottom:20px;   
}
.bottomdiv{
overflow-y: scroll; 
margin:3px;
width:392px;
height:350px;
display:block;
border:1px solid blue;        
}
```

---

SCRIPT

---

```
 function uparrow(){
 $('.updiv').slideToggle();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave the parent container a fixed height of `400px`, means the problem is that you're forcing it to have that height no matter what, [just remove it](http://jsfiddle.net/bZE63/).

Comment: this is a issue that Container must not change the size. it should be a fix size...

Comment: @SergiuCostas so when the first div is expanded, and the 3rd div goes down, a part of it should be hidden?

Comment: No, the height of DIV-3 must change to suit the Container

Comment: indeed it can be a solution to add to container CSS overflow:hidden; - but I hope it exists better solution :)